# Spring security нет доступа к контроллеру регистрации

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

Пробую прикрутить на свой [тестовый проект](https://github.com/KENTyku/SpringDataJpaJava/tree/springMvcJpaAopRestfulJavaconfig_dev_change_clientEntity) Spring security по [инструкции](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/jc.html). Создал свою страницу входа(заглушку), форму регистрации. Настроил security. При тестировании все ссылки, разрешенные для всех в SecurityConfig, доступны кроме ссылки на контроллер "registrationClient". При попытке пройти по иным ссылкам перенаправляет на страницу входа.
Не могу понять, почему Spring security не позволяет мне отправить данные jsp формы регистрации в контроллер для их обработки. При этом браузер отображает 403 ошибку:

```
Type Status Report
Message Forbidden
Description The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.
```

В остальном же корректно отрабатывает. Прошу помощи.

Мой код:

SecurityConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/resources/images/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/registration").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/registrationClient").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()

                .and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/resources/loginPage.html").permitAll();
    }       
}
```

registration.jsp:

```html
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>LoginPage</title>
</head>
<body>
Регистрация на сайте:
<form method="POST" action="registrationClient" enctype="text/plain">
     <table>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Логин:</b></td>
            <td><input name="login" type="text" id="login_registration"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Пароль:</b></td>
            <td><input name="password" type="password" id="password_registration"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Подтверждение пароля:</b></td>
            <td><input name="passwordConfirm" type="password" id="passwordConfirm_registration"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Зарегистрироваться"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

RegistrationController.java:

```
    @Controller
public class RegistrationController {
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Autowired
    private ClientRepository clientRepository;

 @RequestMapping(value = {"/registrationClient"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addClientAccount(
            @RequestParam String login,
            @RequestParam String password,
            @RequestParam String passwordConfirm,
            Model model
    ) {
        System.out.println(login+password+passwordConfirm);
            //логика обработки формы     
            return "redirect:/";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение. В Spring Security 4.x включена по умолчанию Защита от Межсайтовой подделки запроса (CSRF) , поэтому ее надо либо корректно настраивать (тут это не рассматриваю), либо отключить(для новичка вполне можно на этапе изучения, но при реальной разработке без этого нельзя, т.к. современное веб приложение считается уязвимым). Именно она (защита) срабатывала, когда я пытался обратиться к контроллерам. Отключение делается в SecurityConfig.java: (добавляем .csrf().disable())

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/resources/images/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/registration").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/registrationClient").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()

                .and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/resources/loginPage.html").permitAll();
    }       
}
```